# C# Convert Object to list<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, object

I am trying to store the dates from the first row into a list string. How do I convert them to a list string from an object?

```
public List<string> populateDates(string id)
{
    List<string> dates = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        object o = table.Rows[1][i];
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }

    return dates;
}
```

Comment: What's `table` and why are you storing dates as strings? Can you show us an example of what `table.Rows[1][i]` is?

Comment: All you need dates.Add(o.ToString()); it will stores date / datetime in string format

Comment: @DourHighArch table is a data table....I am trying to store times from an excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the items to your List. You can call `ToString` to convert the item to a string. For example:

```
public List<string> populateDates(string id)
{
    List<string> dates = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        dates.Add(table.Rows[1][i].ToString());
    }

    return dates;
}
```

Comment: This complies but it does not display the dates.

Comment: is it possible to cast what I have into a list string? because its outputting correctly it is just not in the string list format.

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow down your method to a nice one-liner:

```
public List<string> populateDates(string id)
{
    return table[0].Select(d => d.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Take whole first row. Select each item in it and execute `ToString()` on it. Wrap the result into a list.

As a side note, `DateTime` struct gives you quite a few methods to return different forms of date and time strings. Some of them: `ToLongTimeString`, `ToShortDateString`. Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Also, if you are accessing the first row of your array then you should use the index `0` not `1` (as it is in your example).